# Node.js stream pipe

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, stream

I'm developing a file importer, I decide to move with the stream approach, I have a series of step that I must follow to reach my goal, that can see below:

1. Download the file.
2. Parse to CSV
3. Validate the entire file.
4. "Translate" and save on db

Here is the snippet that pipe then all:

```
protected async pipe(readable: Readable, transform: Transform, validator: Transform, importer: T) {
    const asyncPipeline = promisify(pipeline);
    try {
        await asyncPipeline(readable, transform, validator, importer)
        logger.info("Import Finished")
    } catch (error) {
        const { message, stack } = error
        logger.error(message, { stack })
    }
}
```

Here is the snippet that calls the pipe method above

```
super.pipe(
    response // response from http.get, 
    csv()    // csv-parser library, 
    new Validator(), 
    new Importer()
)
```

The Validator class:

```
export class Validator extends Transform {
    constructor() {
        super({ objectMode: true })
    }

    _transform(chunk: any, encoding: string, done: any) {
        this.push(chunk)
        logger.info("Validating", { chunk })
        done()
    }

    _flush(done: any) {
        done()
    }
}
```

and finally the importer class:

```
export class Importer extends Writable {
    private buffer: Car[]

    constructor() {
        super({ objectMode: true })
        this.buffer = new Array()
    }

    _write(row: object, enc: string, next: any) {
        this.import(row)
            .then(() => next())
            .catch((error: Error) => next(error))
    }

    private async import(data: any): Promise<Car[]> {
        this.buffer.push(data)
        logger.info(this.buffer.length.toString());
        return await db.save(data) // fake method;
    }
}
```

When super.pipe is called the output is alternating from "Validation" and the total size of the buffer array.

```
{"level":30,"time":1588773096585,"pid":40537,"msg":"1"}
{"level":30,"time":1588773096586,"pid":40537,"msg":"Validating"}
{"level":30,"time":1588783063275,"pid":61571,"msg":"Importation finished"}
{"level":30,"time":1588773096633,"pid":40537,"msg":"2"}
```

There's a way, that first? I execute the validator stream, and after go to the importer stream?

Comment: I'm not 100% comfortable with stream objects and this looks like Typescript, but it seems reasonable. I don't understand how your output alternates between "1", "Validating", and "2" in the output display. The only "Validating" I see is in a log message. Can you simplify further so we can see the input and output of only the code in question?

Comment: these number, 1 and 2 are the size of an array, that I push elements to it, the input it's a CSV file that is mapped to a key/value object

Comment: I don't want to ignore your response; it wasn't clear to me initially that the last block was from the logger routine. However, I still think that the example needs to be a runnable standalone test case. What I tend to do is use the stream.PassThrough class to isolate my logic and emit events, but I'm not sure that's helpful for you.